# Why WPF ScrollViewer Language is tr but ContextMenu command texts are in English?

Tags: wpf, localization, scrollviewer, turkish

I have a ScrollViewer in WPF. when I make right click to scroll control, context menu is opening and write commands like "Scroll Here, "Scroll Top" vs. vs.
although my ScrollViwer Language is "tr-Tr" , Why Scrollviewer ContextMenu command texts are in English ?

Answer (score 1):

you must do these 2 steps:

1. Either run a Turkish Windows or install Turkish MUI onEnglish Windows

UPDATE: Actually you need .NET FW Turkish Languaga Pack installed. In Windows Vista or Win7 you just need to to install MUI. For WinXP install .NET FW Turkish Languaga Pack from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=41C61D2A-D411-4DDE-9013-BB08EB688BB6&displaylang=en

2. Modify your App.xaml.cs as:

public partial class App : Application
    {
        static App()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
        }

```
}
```

Regards
Kubilay